# Blazor - Dependency Injection is not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I have a very strange problem in my Blazor project. I am using Dependency Inject to user my "CompanyService" service. Here is how I am registering my service

```
// Servies Injection
services.AddSingleton<UserService, UserService>();
services.AddSingleton<CompanyService, CompanyService>();
```

And I am injecting that service in my razor component as

```
@inject CompanyService CompanyService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
```

I need to pass these services to my ViewModel and I am doing like this (CompanesList is my Razor component name so it is constructor)

```
public CompaniesList()
{
    Context = new CompaniesListVm(NavigationManager, CompanyService);
}
```

When I debug this code, I always get services as null (both NavigationManager, CompanyService). Here is my file position in my project

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this?

P.S I am also using MatBlazor for my UI.

Thank you

Regards
J

Comment: You should inject `CompaniesListVm` instead IMO. avoid `new` as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was:

I was initializing my VM in constructor, which is wrong

```
public CompaniesList()
{
    Context = new CompaniesListVm(NavigationManager, CompanyService);
}
```

After changing to

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     Context = new CompaniesListVm(NavigationManager, CompanyService);
}
```

All works fine.

Regards

Comment: This was my exact issue.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
services.AddSingleton<UserService, UserService>();
services.AddSingleton<CompanyService, CompanyService>();
```

It should be:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
services.AddSingleton<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
```

But if you did not define interfaces, then it should be:

```
services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
services.AddSingleton<CompanyService>();
```

Where do you do this

```
 public CompaniesList()
{
   Context = new CompaniesListVm(NavigationManager, CompanyService);
 }
```

Show all your code...

In any case, use the @inject directive in the view portion (Razor markups) of your component, or define a property annotated with the Inject attribute, as for instance:

```
[Inject] Public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps...